# Signal Sigabrt while renaming Xcode app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, rename, sigabrt

I was trying to rename an app like I regularly do. I go to the project title at the top left, double tap, and rename the app.

[image]

It usually works. However, this time, I have come across a Signal Sigabrt. I tried renaming the project only, but that doesn't work. All of the connections seem to be correct. Here is my error.

[image]

This is the first time I have come across a Signal Sigabrt for this reason. Could someone show me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Update

When I keep the name of the project the same as the original one, the app runs fine. If I change it to the new one, the app crashes. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: Renaming the project and "renaming the app" are different things... I think renaming the **product** qualifies more as "renaming the app". Just my opinion...

Comment: I have tried cleaning it. Unfortunately that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you posted indicates problem in one of your Interface Builder files. Most likely the outlet connections defined there are not correct anymore.

Comment: That is what I realized. However, when checking the outlet, it seemed to be fine...

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot suggestion, but have you been adding and removing objects to the view, or creating and renaming your Outlets? Sometimes this can result in outlets in the xib file which no longer exist in the header or implementation files (I can't explain why this is, although I'm sure there's a reasonable explanation.)

In any case, with the **Interface Builder** open check the **Connections Inspector**, which is the button all the way to the right in the **Utilities** panel.  Make sure there are no lingering outlets or actions over there which are not linked to any objects. You may need to cycle through the objects in your view,even the view itself, to make sure you aren't missing any.  If there are any of them listed, delete them and try to run the app again.

Comment: The thing is, when I keep the name of the project the same as the original one, the app runs fine. If I change it to the new one, the app crashes. Should I still try this?